# Header not fixed its move upward when soft keyboard appear in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-keypad

I want to make a layout with fixed header when the keyboard appear.This layout works fine its fixed the header but also show the Title bar. The problem I'm facing is when i hide the Title bar and want to show the layout full screen the header move again when soft keyboard appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <!-- Header aligned to top -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FC9"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:text="Fixed Header"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
  </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"       
         android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I hide the title bar with

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or

```
android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar”
```

the header moves again.

I also add the scrollview in the layout then the problem I'm facing is the header is fixed but the keyboard appear on the editbox and the list is not scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <!-- Header aligned to top -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FC9"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:text="Fixed Header"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
  </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"       
         android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_sv_login_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_ll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also used this but its not work.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

Comment: thats property of android, if you are using fullscreen view the header move upward when keyboard appear..
You can't do anything